# Affine Cipher features ax + b but inverse is a^-1(y-b), how come?

Tags: encryption

I'm studying the Affine Cipher.
The entry in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher) says its to encrypt, you compute:

[image: affine encryption]

and to decrypt you compute:

[image]

I was thinking that you would [a^-1(y) - b] mod m to decrypt.

Why isn't this the case? (what rule, if any, am I not clear on?)

Comment: You may need to post this on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ in order to receive answers on such a specialised question.

Comment: Please don't vote down but close the question, as it could be a fine question on crypto.stackexchange.com (if it is not a dupe)

Comment: Well, it is not really a good question anywhere. It is simply a case of solving y = a*x + b correctly, which is simply a matter of high school algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a^-1(y - b). It's just the notation that's throwing you off. Notice that they define D(x) with x as the variable. It's just the same as D(y) = a^-1(y - b)